# How can I get the results of a search in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am developing a eclipse plugin, I need to get or store the results of a query search (java seach ctrl+H) in eclipse.

Once I made a search (java seach ctrl+H) I need to get or store the results in a data structure so as to manipulate it.

java search method add:

[image]

I need to manipulate this results in a data structure:

[image]

I only need to look for methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to searches using:

```java
NewSearchUI.addQueryListener(listener);
```

where `listener` is a class implementing `IQueryListener`. This interface has a number of methods called as queries progress. They all have an `ISearchQuery` parameter. `ISearchQuery` has the method

```java
ISearchResult getSearchResult()
```

which you can call to get the search result `ISearchResult`. This has a

```java
void addListener(ISearchResultListener listener)
```

method which lets you listen to the results changing using the:

```java
void searchResultChanged(SearchResultEvent event)
```

method of the interface. `SearchResultEvent` is an abstract class which does not contain much information. Depending on the type of result changing the actual class might be something like `org.eclipse.search.ui.text.MatchEvent` which contains more information.

Comment: NewsearchUI is the view?

Comment: No, it is `org.eclipse.search.ui.NewSearchUI` a class that provides various static methods that form the main interface to the search UI.

Comment: the method `getSearchResult()` return a single result? how can I get all the results list from a query?

Comment: `ISearchResult` is the object that holds the complete result of the search, you use the listener to get told about the individual items in the result.

Comment: How can I tell you that when I don't know anything about your code? You need to set up the query listener some time before you need to see the search results.

Comment: Can I put it in the start method of tha plugin's activator class? so when the plugin starts the query listener is activated.

Comment: The Activator start method is not normally called until something else in the plugin runs. Use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point if you want something to run during Eclipse startup.

Comment: If I look for methods how can I verify if the result match with I am looking for (supossing I know what must be the result)

Comment: Do you have an example where I can get told aboult the individual items of a result and compare the name of the result in case of it was a method? @greg-449

Comment: No, I don't have an example and I can't help any further with this.

Comment: Can I Use an extension point to iterate over the results' list of a search?